# Yum sees no packages

Tags: linux, yum, rhel6

All,

I fear I have royally screwed my linux install and I'm hoping you lovely internet denizens can spare me from my bungling attempts to unscrew myself.

For starters, I'm trying to get wget installed to get me back on my feet.

```
# cat /etc/*-release
Oracle Linux Server release 6.6
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
Oracle Linux Server release 6.6

# yum install wget
Setting up Install Process
No package wget available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I check my enabled repos and I have both RHEL 6server - RPMforge.net and Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64.

Here's what I've tried to no avail

1) yum update

2) yum clean all

3) Installing yum from source.

4) Install nettle, gmaps (or whatever that require library is), and then gnutls from source to get me to wget.  Gnutls gives me an error saying it can't find nettle 2.7.1 when I clearly have it installed in /usr/local/bin

5) Installing various items directly from their rpm package.  I got nowhere quick since rpm doesn't automatically download needed dependencies.

6) The first 4 stages of loss and grief, including denial, anger, bargaining, and depression.

If anyone's got any ideas to get wget and yum back up and running, I'm all ears.

** Update **

Well I thought I'd uninstall and then reinstall yum.  Bad idea.  I try to reinstall yum and it tells me

```
rpm -i yum-3.4.3-155.fc23.noarch.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
pyliblzma is needed by yum-3.4.3-155.fc23.noarch
python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by yum-3.4.3-155.fc23.noarch
pyxattr is needed by yum-3.4.3-155.fc23.noarch
```

Yep, I've got python 2.6 and I can't find where an older version of yum that still uses python 2.6.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing an upgrade on the package.

```
$ wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm


rpm -Uvh yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
```

Relying on the package manager
RPM can help you fix issues like this, or at the very least, help to identify issues. The rpm command includes the ability to verify the packages it maintains.

```
 $ rpm -V yum
```

Comment: Don't have wget.  In the end I decided to just start another server.  I could spend another day trying to fix the problem or I could spend another day re-installing everything.  I chose the latter.